# I have hosted my Loopback 4 application on iisnode windows web app, Getting the port from there as a pipe which Loopback 4 doesn't understand

Tags: node.js, iisnode, loopback4

I have hosted  my loopback 4 application on iisnode windows web app, which is giving the port as pipe and in my loopback 4 application i am reading port as  `Process.env.PORT`. And i am getting the error:

> Cannot start the application. RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received \.\pipe\fde1f2c4-428f-5513-8114-c9520f1ba02d

I tried by manually giving port 80, 443 but that is not working and throwing error like

> EADDRNOTAVAIL

Expected port to be a number but iisnode giving it as pipe, which loopback 4 is rejecting.

```js
    // index.js root file

    const application = require('./dist');

    module.exports = application;

    // Run the application
    const config = {
      rest: {
        port: (process.env.PORT|| 3000),
        host: process.env.WEBSITE_HOSTNAME || "localhost",
        openApiSpec: {
          setServersFromRequest: true,
        },
      },
    };
    application.main(config).catch(err => {
      console.error('Cannot start the application.', err);
      process.exit(1);
    });

    // index.ts inside src

    import {myApplication} from './application';
    import {ApplicationConfig} from '@loopback/core';

    export {myApplication};

    export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
      const app = new myApplication(options);
      await app.boot();
      await app.start();

      const url = app.restServer.url;
      console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);

      return app;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see our response in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3507#issuecomment-518099844. Thanks.